# MongoDB document update array element using findOneAndUpdate method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-java

Can someone look at this issue as we are not able to insert the array in the field 'd' as shown in the image below:

[![JSON Structure in MongoDB][1]][1]

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "articles": "art",
  "author": "author"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/index.html#update-specific-elements-of-an-array-of-documents) to update a specific array element (with a condition). The array filters in Java is defined with `FindOneAndUpdateOptions` object.

```
List<Bson> arrFilters = new ArrayList<>();
arrFilters.add(new Document("elem.apn", "abcdef")); // this specifies the element search criteria
FindOneAndUpdateOptions updateOptions = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions().arrayFilters(arrFilters);

String [] dArray = { "app", "ban", "ora" }; // the "d" array to be added
Bson update = set("session.ps.$[elem].d", Arrays.asList(dArray));

String idStr = "5e37dc262f5ff4dfc935eb6b";
Bson queryFilter = eq("_id", new ObjectId(idStr));

Document result = coll.findOneAndUpdate(queryFilter, update, updateOptions);
System.out.println(result);
```

The same update operation in Mongo Shell:

```
var dArray = [ "app", "ban" ];

db.test.updateOne(
   { _id: ObjectId("5e37dc262f5ff4dfc935eb6b") }, 
   { $set: { "session.ps.$[elem].d" : dArray } },
   {
     arrayFilters: [ { "elem.apn": "abcdef" } ]
   }
)
```

---

[EDIT ADD]

Updating the `apn` simultaneously with a new value "newVal" *and* adding a new string element "gua" to the `d` array (this will add a new array if the array doesn't exist):

```
db.test.updateOne(
   { _id: ObjectId("5e37dc262f5ff4dfc935eb6b") }, 
   { 
     $set: { "session.ps.$[elem].apn": "newVal" }
     $push: { "session.ps.$[elem].d" : "gua" } 
   },
   {
     arrayFilters: [ { "elem.apn": "abcdef" } ]
   }
)
```

The Java code for the above Mongo Shell code:

```
List<Bson> arrayFilters = new ArrayList<>();
arrayFilters.add(new Document("elem.apn", "abcdef"));
FindOneAndUpdateOptions updateOptions = 
    new FindOneAndUpdateOptions().arrayFilters(arrayFilters);   

Bson pushUpdate = push("session.ps.$[elem].d", "gua");
Bson setUpdate = set("session.ps.$[elem].apn", "newValue");
Bson update = combine(pushUpdate, setUpdate);

String idStr = "5e37dc262f5ff4dfc935eb6b";
Bson queryFilter = eq("_id", new ObjectId(idStr));

Document result = coll.findOneAndUpdate(queryFilter, update, updateOptions);
```

Comment: (1) The `eq` and `set` static methods are from `com.mongodb.client.model.Filters` and `com.mongodb.client.model.Updates` classes.

Comment: Thank you but the issue is we need to update the apn field simultaneously which is not happening.

Comment: Please explain _"... we need to update the apn field simultaneously"_.

Comment: I added the Mongo Shell code. Please check if it is what you wanted - the same update query additionally updates the `apn` field with a newly supplied value.

Comment: Thank you again, please let me know how to implement in java

Comment: And one more thing the Array fields in the d array should be added everytime with a new subscript for every update of apn field

Comment: _"Array fields in the d array should be added everytime with a new subscript for every update of apn field"_: Both the field updates are independent, they can be updated together or separately - but the update depends upon the query criteria including the arrayFilters.

Comment: OK,but this is the emergency requirement can you please suggest an alternative

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207172/discussion-between-prasad-and-rakesh).