# MongoTemplate Criteria for Query to update element inside array of objects

Tags: database, mongodb, spring-boot, nosql, mongotemplate

I'm trying to push a comment for a particular answer, I tried various ways, but comments are always getting added to the parent Question, but not for an Answer within that Question.

> **My Database Hierarchy:**
>
> - Question1
>
>   - Comment1
>   - Comment2
>   - Answer1
>
>     - CommentForAnswer1
>   - Answer2

|
[image]
|

**My Model Classes**

**QUESTION.java**

```
@Document(collection = "QUESTION")
public class QUESTION {
    @Id
    private String questionId;
    private String questionHeader;
    private String questionBody;
    private String byUser; //username
    private Instant postedAt;
    private int upVotes;
    private int downVotes;
    private List<ANSWER> answerObj;
    private List<COMMENT> commentObj;
```

**ANSWER.java**

```
public class ANSWER {
    private String answerId;
    private String answerBody;
    private String byUser; //username
    private Instant postedAt;
    private int upVotes;
    private int downVotes;
    private List<COMMENT> commentObj;
```

**COMMENT.java**

```
public class COMMENT {
    private String commentId;
    private String commentBody;
    private String byUser; //username
    private Instant postedAt;
    private int upVotes;
    private int downVotes;
```

**controller**

```
@PostMapping(value = "posts/{questionId}/add")
    public ResponseEntity<?> postComment(@PathVariable String questionId,
                                         @RequestParam(value = "answerId", defaultValue = "") String answerId,
                                         @RequestBody PostCommentRequest postCommentRequest,
                                         Authentication authentication) {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        PostCommentResponse postCommentResponse = postService.postAComment(postCommentRequest, username, questionId, answerId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(postCommentResponse.getMessage());
    }
```

**repository**

```
update.push("commentObj", comment);
try {
    query.addCriteria(answerId.isEmpty() ?
            (new Criteria("questionId").is(questionId)) :
            (new Criteria("answerObj.answerId").is(answerId).andOperator(Criteria.where("questionId").is(questionId))));
    mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, QUESTION.class, QUESTION_COLLECTION);
    return new PostCommentResponse("Successfully updated!", comment);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return new PostCommentResponse("Failed to update, Reason: " + e.toString(), null);
}
```

Can Somebody help me to figure out the criteria for query which can push object in array which is inside another array of objects.

Edit: MongoDB version 4.0 (latest)

Comment: post please what is your MongoDB version

Comment: Here is a similar question (and answer) but, using MongoDB Java driver; are you looking for _similar functionality_?: [MongoDB document update array element using findOneAndUpdate method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60035042/mongodb-document-update-array-element-using-findoneandupdate-method-in-java/60036418#60036418)

Answer (score 0):

That's my suggestion for this case:

```java
public Mono<ProjectChild> UpdateCritTemplChild(
       String id, String idch, String ownername) {

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id")
                              .is(id));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("tasks._id")
                              .is(idch));

    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("tasks.$.ownername", ownername);

    return template
         // findAndModify:
         // Find/modify/get the "new object" from a single operation.
         .findAndModify(
              query, update,
              new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true), ProjectChild.class
                       )
         ;

  }
```