# Push into nested object array with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have collection with a document structure that looks like this:

```
{
    id : 1,
    name : "height",
    datasets : [
        {
            version : 1.1,
            data : [{x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 1, y: 2}]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to push another object `{x: 2, y: 3}`  to the 'data' array of an object in 'datasets' where 'version' is 1.1.

I've tried multiple combinations but I don't seem to get the right one.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: You can update the nested array using the [filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with).

Comment: Here is a post with an answer about pushing a document into a nested array: [How to add a json in a nested array of a mongodb document using Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701824/how-to-add-a-json-in-a-nested-array-of-a-mongodb-document-using-spring). The post shows three levels of nesting; but, you can use the same technique and apply for your case.

Comment: @whoami yes it did.