# MongoDB - Update a key in Object in a Document's Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Assume we have the following collection, which I have a few questions about:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f560d4b5d4b4a0013e6fe34"),
    "places": [
        {
            "_id": "5f55d5c643b7370013605513",
            "stores": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f55d5c643b7370013605514",
                    "open": false
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5f55d5c643b7370013605512",
                    "open": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f3b8d7194beb72ec8975639",
            "stores": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f55eb98ed8c3a2af29fa395",
                    "open": false
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5f55eba2ed8c3a2af29fa39b",
                    "open": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find 1 store with `_id` at `stores` and update key `open` of this store to `true`.

Comment: Is `places` a collection or is it just a property of a collection?

Comment: ```places``` is a Key in a Collection

Comment: You can use `updateOne` method with `arrayFilters` option to find and update a specific `stores#_id` and update its `open` value.

Comment: ```Thank you!```

Comment: You can use this post as an example to update a nested array: [How to add a json in a nested array of a mongodb document using Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701824/how-to-add-a-json-in-a-nested-array-of-a-mongodb-document-using-spring)

Comment: Thank [prasad_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4679320/prasad). I solved my problem with ```arrayFilters```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update specific sub-document with `arrayFilters` options of an update query.

As per your example if you want to update a sub-document places' stores which have `_id` is `5f55eb98ed8c3a2af29fa395` then you can use the following query to update.

```
 db.collection.update({match-record},
 {
   "$set":{
      "places.stores.$[elem].open": true
    }
 },
 {
    "arrayFilters": [{
        "elem._id": "5f55eb98ed8c3a2af29fa395"            
    }],
    "multi": true
 });
```

**Note:** This will work in mongo `3.6+` versions only.

For more info: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered